# Programatically add "Spacing to nearest neighbour" constraint

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Is there a way to add a "Spacing to nearest neighbour" constraint programmatically? I saw a similar question posted but I don't think it was in Swift (I'm a beginner when it comes to developing iOS apps).
I haven't tried anything yet as I'm not sure where to start, but thought it might be something along the lines of:

```
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nearestNeighbour.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

I want to have it such that the scrollView I have in the top half of the screen is a certain distance from the nearest button below. I can't constrain it to the specific button though because I don't have IBOutlets and would rather not add them.

Comment: Please provide what you tried so far?

Comment: And How you don't know that where you want to put ui component ?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `UIStackView`?

Comment: I'm not sure what a UIStackView is but I just want it so that my scrollView is always x spaces above my button, no matter the screen size (iPhone XS Max or iPhone 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't constrain it to the specific button though because I don't have IBOutlets and would rather not add them

Then you are totally stuck. Your requirements are self contradictory. Without a reference to the button of *some* kind, you cannot possibly make a constraint to it programmatically. There is no “whoever my nearest neighbor is” reference.

Comment: Thanks, that was all I was trying to figure out, whether it was possible or not.